# How to set the Entitlement in Xcode for osx app?

Tags: xcode, macos

My app needs to save some information as a `html` file, and if I select the `Use Entitlements` file and `sand box`, my app won't be able to save the `html` file at any location in the file system. If I don't select `Use Entitlements`, would my app be rejected by `Apple`?

Also, this version of my app doesn't use `iCloud`，but my next version might. Can the `Use Entitlements` and `iCloud` both be selected or not?

Comment: As @trojanfoe explained, the app must be in a sandbox for the app store, so yes, you must use Entitlements. As for iCloud, if you're submitting an app which doesn't use iCloud features, don't select the iCloud entitlement. You may be able to add it later, should a future update require it. I would expect Apple to reject any app that requests an entitlement, but doesn't require it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it looks like that it's better to select the Entitlement and not select the iCloud now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will only accept sandboxed apps for submission into the app store.

In order to save the HTML file, you can ask the user where to save it, in which case you can save it anywhere the user has access, or you could save it into the app's container, where you have unlimited access.

Comment: I use the NSSavePanel,NSURL* fileURL = [panel directoryURL];this url is the app's container.

Comment: @gohamgx No, that URL will be whatever is chosen by the user and doesn't have to be within the app's container.

Comment: Yes,this is a bug for my app.Thank you for help me to find it.I used the deprecated api.